# Trying to work with RetrofitClient and subscribe, having trouble with Kotlin

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, retrofit, subscribe

I am trying to set up a user registration and login, and have been following a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xq2FUJvE-c)

I am also transitioning from java to kotlin while learning android programming vs just desktop, so a lot of new stuff for me. Anyways, code im tring to replicate:

```
  compositeDisposable.add(iMyService.loginUser(email,password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                     @Override
                     public void accept(String response) throws Exception {
                     Toast.makeText(Mainactivity.this,""+response,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                }));
```

In Kotlin I have:

```
    compositeDisposable.add(iMyService.loginUser(email,password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(Consumer<String>() {

        }))
```

Not sure how to proceed and fill in the rest. I am not familiar with the subscribe method

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin it would be some something like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(iMyService.loginUser(email,password)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe({ response: String ->
           Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }, { t: Throwable? ->
      })
```

you can refer to this link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/384-reactive-programming-with-rxandroid-in-kotlin-an-introduction

Comment: I tried this, but when i actually try to log in it always go to the error. Doesn't verify the email. Soon as I remove the throwable component it crashes upon log in attempts. Not sure what is going on. I am able to verify login on the port (3000) with ARC